# setting up ubuntu server 12.04 with SSD/HDDs questions

Tags: partitioning, directory, ssd, raid, home-directory

I am setting up Ubuntu server 12.04 LTS.
I am using 120GB SSD for OS and 3x4TB in RAID 5 (software RAID 5)
Here are my partitions that I configured during the initial installation:
/, /boot, swap on SSD, and /home on RAID 5

I did it like this so I can use the SSD only for SSD, nothing else. and I want all of my data to be stored on the RAID 5 HDD.

My question is, when creating a directory to be shared through Samba, do those directories have to be made under /home folder?

In other words,

If I create a directory such as "/datastorage/video", instead of "/home/datastorage/video", and I put all my movie files there, will those movie files be stored on the RAID 5 HDDs?

Basically I just want to know if "/home" partition is the same as "/home" folder.

Thanks a lot guys. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as long as the `/home` partition is mounted, everything in `/home` is stored on that partition.